# Landlord entry into property - 24 hour notice

Tags: landlord, new-mexico

New Mexico Statute [§ 47-8-15](https://codes.findlaw.com/nm/chapter-47-property-law/nm-st-sect-47-8-24.html) says:

> *...the owner may enter the resident's dwelling unit pursuant to this subsection only after giving the resident twenty-four hours written notification of his intent to enter, the purpose for entry and the date and reasonable estimate of the time frame of the entry;*

Consider the case of renting a house with a fenced backyard. Is entry into the yard subject to 24 hour notice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is entry into the yard subject to 24 hour notice?

Most likely it is.

Note that [section § 47-8-3](https://codes.findlaw.com/nm/chapter-47-property-law/nm-st-sect-47-8-3.html) defines both *dwelling unit* and *premises*. The latter encompasses the term "*appurtenances*", which the [Black's Law Dictionary](http://heimatundrecht.de/sites/default/files/dokumente/Black%27sLaw4th.pdf) defines, *inter alia*, as "*an adjunct; an appendage; [...] garden [...]*".

At least in the context of *fenced* backyard, the fact that § 47-8-3 defines *dwelling unit* and *premises* separately does not exclude "*premises*" from the scope of § 47-8-15. That is because the fence is "*a structure [...] or part of a structure [...] that is used as a home, residence*". Indeed, the existence of the fence suggests that the backyard is intended for only that tenant's exclusive use/enjoyment, with the implications it has on tenant's privacy.